# Advanced matching / scoring with MongoDB on a set of answers / questions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have user data that looks like this:

```
{
    name: 'Some Name',
    uid: 'rew54bth324'
    // Can be 1000s
    answers: {
       do_you_like_cars: 'Prefer bikes',
       hotels_or_hostels: 'Tents!',
       vegan: 'Pesca',
    },
    // Can be 100,000s.
    usersSeenThisUser: [
        'wgwewg343',
        'vyuzx3tg'
    ],
    lat: 32.0,
    lng: 43.5
}
```

Another user has answered a set of questions as well, some of them might be the same.
My question is: How would I get a list of results based on how many answers are the same/similar (at least 1) while ignoring users seen this user.

In ElasticSearch this is extremely easy with a 'should' query, and it also gives you max score + score for each result.

What would be the query in Mongo

Comment: what all fields do you need in response & how many user docs could be there in your collection, Plus what exactly score meant for ?

Comment: @whoami sorry was asleep, millions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /** Optional - Remove unnecessary fields to reduce document size  */
  { $project: { usersSeenThisUser: 0 } },
  /** Convert 'answers' object to array [{k:...,v:...},{k:...,v:...}] */
  { $addFields: { answers: { $objectToArray: "$answers" } } },
  /** Unwind 'answers' array inorder to group similar answered question & it's value */
  { $unwind: "$answers" },
  /** Group on k & v & push user who has similar answers */
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { k: "$answers.k", v: "$answers.v" },
      users: { $push: "$name" }
    }
  },
  /** match docs(answers) which has two or more users */
  { $match: { $expr: { $gte: [{ $size: "$users" }, 2] } } },
  /** Group on 'users' array where two user's array is same & push all answers to 'answers' array */
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$users",
      answers: {
        $push: "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  /** Transform fields to the way required, answers array of objects to a single object {k:v,k:v} */
  {
    $project: { _id: 0, users: "$_id", answers: { $arrayToObject: "$answers" } }
  }
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-YAMvT2xslR)

Comment: Amazing man thanks, I'm going to do a one million user test on this, any advice for the correct indexes? Also, the idea is to get a set of users 'matches' to this user and avoid ones they have already 'swiped' past, think Tinder dating (Not what the app is)

Comment: @Oliver Dixon : Does this *avoid ones they have already 'swiped' past* ? mean avoid users in `usersSeenThisUser` even if their answers do match with given user ? So you're looking for an user & his related users whose answers do match..

Comment: It's two things, users who might have answers that relate, sorted by score (aka the number who has the highest match) and users that have not seen each other.

Comment: @OliverDixon : Right now in the provided test playground query is doing operation on all users is that correct or is by any chance do you pass-in a user name(Some Name) & get all users who has given same answers as (Some Name) ? Cause the complexity differs a lot between these two requirements

Comment: do you know if it's even possible performant? We currently use Elastic which auto indexes all the answers; the problem is we don't like having two databases since elastic isn't safe. (Other database is Firestore which has only basic query but 99.99% SLA)

Comment: @OliverDixon : Unless you do it for just one user if definitely not performance oriented, Also having arrays with thousands of elements is also not preferable additionally from my experience even after having MongoDB as DB server, we still had elastic search for these kind of operations with syncing data between these two..

Comment: yeah we might just stick with ElasticSearch and Firestore, yes I have 36 active clients at the moment with millions of users :-)